# Bootstrap Typeahead not working in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Typeahead is not working Angular 1.0.8 js version but is working fine in 1.2.24 version.

My application is old one and client don't want to install new version because of some other compatibility issues with jquery and Telerik controls.

How can I resolve this ? Here is my code.

```
 <div class="btn-group" style="height: 70%; margin-bottom:5px;">
      <input type="text" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-model="holdOrder.ServiceCenterName" ng-disabled="disabled"  />

     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li ng-repeat="svCenter in holdOrder.ServiceCenters">
            <a href="" ng-click="setSelectedSC(svCenter)">{{svCenter.Fullname}}</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ngAutocomplete](https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete) which is an older module that hasn't been updated in a few months, but works just fine on Angular 1.0.8.

Some examples [**here**](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete) (plunkers with angular 1.0.8).

Comment: I updated the code above. Can you please help me in get this ?

Comment: Well, you're giving me the code of a dropdown menu. That's neither Typeahead nor ngAutocomplete.

Comment: I want Typeahead in Drop down

Comment: @user3757426 I don't think you want `Typeahead`(s) inside a dropdown. But if that's what you really want, just place your inputs inside the dropdown.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to place my inputs inside dropdown ?

Comment: @user3757426 Little bit of research would get you [that](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7dc/), and then you'd just have to replace them with typeaheads. Also, please remember SO is not supposed to be a "*do my homework for me*" kind of website. Some people will do it for you, I won't.